# Spring Data JPA on multiple columns with AND clause and combining with OR clause

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, querydsl, predicate

I have a table structure as follows

```
BrandMerchant(id,brand_id,category_id,merchant_id)
```

We have a List in our request and I would like to create a query as :

```
Select * 
from BrandMerchant 
where (brand_id=1 and merchant_id=2 and category_id=3) 
   OR (brand_id=4 and merchant_id=5 and category_id=6) 
   OR (brand_id=5 and merchant_id=4 and category_id=6)`
```

...some more depending the list size.

I want something similar to `findByBrandIdAndMerchantIdAndCategoryId` on a collection(`List<BrandMerchant>`)

How to implement the above statement using spring data jpa or by generating custom query in java

Comment: @Query annotation and gogogogogog.

Comment: I agree with @Antoniossss but also you can use Specification<T>. Here you can find more in [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#specifications)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with [FluentJPA](https://github.com/streamx-co/FluentJPA). Assuming:

- List contains tuples of brand, merchant and category ids
- BrandMerchant defines corresponding access properties

```java
public List<BrandMerchant> findMerchants(List<Integer[]> params) {

    Function1<BrandMerchant, Boolean> dynamicFilter = buildOr(params);

    FluentQuery query = FluentJPA.SQL((BrandMerchant m) -> {
        SELECT(m);
        FROM(m);
        WHERE(dynamicFilter.apply(m));
    });
    return query.createQuery(em, BrandMerchant.class).getResultList();
}

private Function1<BrandMerchant, Boolean> buildOr(List<Integer[]> params) {
    Function1<BrandMerchant, Boolean> criteria = Function1.FALSE();

    for (Integer[] tuple : params) {
        int brandId = tuple[0];
        int merchantId = tuple[1];
        int categoryId = tuple[2];
        criteria = criteria.or(m -> m.getBrand().getId() == brandId &&
                                    m.getMerchant().getId() == merchantId &&
                                    m.getCategory().getId() == categoryId);
    }

    return criteria;
}
```

produces the following SQL:

```
SELECT t0.* 
FROM t0 
WHERE (((t0.brand = 1) AND ((t0.merchant = 2) AND (t0.category = 3))) OR
 ((t0.brand = 4) AND ((t0.merchant = 5) AND (t0.category = 6))))
```

More details on [Dynamic Queries](https://github.com/streamx-co/FluentJPA/wiki/Dynamic-Queries) and [JPA Respositories integration](https://github.com/streamx-co/FluentJPA/wiki/JPA-Repositories).